# Applying Minkowski's Inequality for four terms

Tags: inequality

I would like to apply Minkowski's inequality for this,
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-52)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2+(z-c_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2+(z-c_1)^2}$$

Given that $x, y, z$ are non-negative numbers and the others are constants.

But as I apply Minkowski's inequality, I get different answers, such as

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-52)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2+(z-c_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2+(z-c_1)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(52-x)^2+(-y)^2+(-z)^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2+(z-c_1)^2}+\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+(b_2-y)^2+(c_1-z)^2}$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x+52-x)^2+(y-y)^2+(z-z)^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_1+a_2-x)^2+(y-b_1+b_2-y)^2+(z-c_1-z+c_1)^2}$$
$$=52+\sqrt{(a_2-a_1)^2+(b_2-b_1)^2}$$

If I did this from another angle, we have
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-52)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2+(z-c_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2+(z-c_1)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(x-52)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{(a_1-x)^2+(b_1-y)^2+(c_1-z)^2}+\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+(b_2-y)^2+(c_1-z)^2}$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x+x-52+a_1-x+a_2-x)^2+(y+y+b_1-y+b_2-y)^2+(z+z+c_1-z+c_2-z)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{(-52+a_1+a_2)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2+(c_1+c_2)^2}$$

How do I ensure that my answer is correct?